# How to consult data with django forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm playing with Django and I have a situation where I have a form and the user define a two dates, like when we need to book a flight, departure date and return date. In my `forms.py` I have a Form class with two fields for dates

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    dateOne = forms.DateTimeField()
    dateTwo = forms.DateTimeField()
```

I need to retrieve objects from a model by passing the dates defined by the user. In my template I'm using get action, on form html tag, but I'm stuck on how I can make this consult and bring the objects to the template.

If I need create a logic on my `views.py` or in my `forms.py`. Does anyone know some thing to me start this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to create an additional view that accepts an AJAX request and sends back a JSON response with the objects you're looking for. So if the user enters two dates you POST/GET those dates to the backend and then your view looks something like this:

```
class SomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        object_list = YourObject.objects.filter(date__range=[start_date, end_date])
        # Do something to your object_list to make it a JSON serializable list
        return JsonResponse({'object_list': object_list})
```

Comment: thanks, I get your idea and create a classmethod in my model instead create this at the view